# Java Two-Way Linked Set data-structure

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, set

Is there an implementation of the following data-structure already implemented in Java:

Say I want the set for `'2' ('A', 'C', 'D')` but I also want the set for `'A' ('1', '2')`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have no such data structure in the Java Collections Framework.

I suggest you the [guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you may find something useful there.

Note that what you have here is essentially a undirected graph so keep an eye out for graph libraries (for example [JGraphT](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht)), or write your own.

Comment: Looks like a case for Guava's [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) class.

Comment: @Henrik nope, that's 1:1

Comment: This is a graph not a `BiMap` sadly.

Comment: Well, a mythical mix of BiMap and MultiMap may be needed ...

Comment: That is not a good idea imho. It is not obvious only for the author of the code that he is using it as a graph. He should use a graph object for this.

Comment: @Henrik @AdamArold `BiMultimap` whould do. Guava devs [closed issue requesting it](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/394) (they implemented it internally already), I guess risk of "graph semantics included" is one of reasons why they don't want to include it with general purpose library.